# Проверить ключ-массив в цикле функцией strpos()

Tags: php, foreach

Есть массив

```
    my_array
    (
    [delimiter_classification] => Array
            (
                [row_title] => Классификация
            )

        [item_cat_name] => Array
            (
                [row_title] => Тип
                [31] => Умные часы и браслеты
                [15] => Умные часы и браслеты
                [14] => Умные часы и браслеты
                [16] => Умные часы и браслеты
            )

        [item_sub_cat_name] => Array
            (
                [row_title] => Подтип
                [31] => Фитнес-браслет
                [15] => Умные часы
                [14] => Умные часы
                [16] => Умные часы
            )
)
```

Нужно пройтись по массиву таким образом:

```
    foreach($my_array as $key){
    if(strpos($key_name, 'delimiter') === 0){
    ...
    }else{
    ...
    }

}
```

Только `$key` тоже массив и `strpos()` с ним не работает. Как проверить этот ключ на наличие "delimiter"? Или альтернатива какая-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    if(strpos($key, 'delimiter') !== false){
     foreach($my_array[$key] as $inner_value){
           Выводим массив под delimiter
     }
    }else{
    foreach($my_array[$key] as $inner_value){
           Выводим массив сравнения
     }
    }
```

вариант 2

```
foreach(array_keys($my_array) as $key){
```

Comment: Спасибо, но первый вариант не подходит, так как мне по массиву `$key` нужно пройтись циклом внутри цикла. А второй вариант не соввсем понял, как мы будем там искать "delimiter"

Comment: @Torawhite Так вам надо рекурсивно?

Comment: @Torawhite Даже так лучше - опишите алгоритм, который вам надо реализовать, так как из вопроса я понял, что вам просто надо начти ключи первой вложенности имеющие в имени 'delimiter'

Comment: Суть вот в чём - взгляните на массив выше, это таблица сравнения товаров. Если в названии ключа есть 'delimiter', то это общий разделитель и я его вывожу одним образом, иначе - прохожу циклом по массиву: вывожу название ряда, а потом вывожу параметры каждого товара (они индексами цифрами). И так далее

Comment: @Torawhite тогда все отлично подходит, и первый и второй вариант. Чуть поправил ответ, чтоб было понятней.

Comment: спасибо большое! Честно говоря, не знал, что  можно проходить внутри `foreach` таким способом `$my_array[$key]` всегда проходил через `$key` тут-то мне php-машина ошибку и выдавала, при наличии `=>$value` у родительского цикла...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте рекурсию

```
function doSomething($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            doSomething($val);
        } elseif (strpos($key, 'delimiter') === 0) {
            //         ...
        } else {
            //         ...
        }
    }
}

doSomething($my_array);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а по массиву `$key` я смогу внутри пройтись циклом?

Comment: @Torawhite `$key` не может быть массивом — это ключ. А ключи бывают в php числовые и строковые.